# Powershell Hashtable Add/Remove Methods affect all varables.

Tags: powershell, methods, hashtable

Here's an example of some strangeness that I've been attempting to overcome, the end result is that I want to have a new variable with the combined hash tables, but without modifying the two original hash tables.

Example: I have two Hash tables.

```
    $User = @{
        "Name" = "Jane Doe"
        "Location" = "Work"
        }
    $Details = @{
        "hair" = "Brown"
        "Eyes" = "Blue"
        "Height" = "68"
        }
```

and I want to add one to the other, and copy the result to a new variable. Few examples:

```
    $newHash = $User.add("Details",$Details)

    ($newHash = $User).add("Details",$Details)

    $newHash = $User
    $newHash.add("Details",$Details)
```

The last two work at adding details, but they add it to both $newHash and $User! If you run the third example, and then remove details:

```
   $User.Remove("Details")
```

It removes it from both $User and $newHash! I cant seem to figure a way around this behavior, suggestions very appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$User = @{
          "Name" = "Jane Doe"
          "Location" = "Work"
    }
$Details = @{
             "hair" = "Brown"
             "Eyes" = "Blue"
             "Height" = "68"
            }

$newHash = $User.clone()
$newHash.Add('Details',$details)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to point out that this isn't strange behavior but is actually by design.  When you say

```
$newHash = $User
```

you're making a shallow copy of $User, and now both $newHash and $User point to the same memory space.  In other words, $newHash is now simply a pointer to the same data as $User.  This is why when you update one, the other also gets updated. Mjolinor has done it the correct way by cloning $User rather than simply pointing to it.

See here:

[What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Answer (score 1):

.Clone() is one correct path, but it's somewhat dangerous, in that a cloned hashtable actually doesn't do the same exact thing as a regular hashtable when it comes to case-sensitivity of the keys.  Cloned hashtables will copy the data, but not the little bit of information that a PowerShell hashtable will use to make keys case-insensitive by default.

Luckily, you can add two hashtables together in PowerShell, which gives you a really easy workaround:

```
$NewHash = @{} + $User
```

Comment: Can you provide some documentation about this or perhaps an example? I'm not finding this to be true in v.4, but perhaps it is true in earlier versions?